# What Am i missing? While Loop

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Trying to create a payroll calculator with a while loop.  I have hit a road block in the process.

```
    name='1'
    print('We pay your employees payroll!')
    while name != '0':
        name=input("\nEnter employee or Enter '0' to quit: ")
        pr=float(input("Enter Payrate: "))
        hrs=float(input("Enter Hours Worked: "))
        if hrs <= 40:
            print("Hours Worked: ", hrs)
            print("Payrate: ", pr)
            print("Basepay:", hrs*pr)
        elif hrs > 40:
            print('Hours Worked: ', hrs)
            print("Payrate: ", pr)
            print("Overtime Rate: ", pr*1.5)
            print("Overtime Hours: ", hrs-40)
            print("Basepay: ", (hrs-40)*pr)
            print("Overtime Pay: ", (pr*1.5)*(hrs-40))
            print("Grosspay: ", (pr*1.5)*(hrs-40)+(pr*hrs))
    print("Employees Paid, Goodbye!")
```

The loop works great, the issue is when entering '0' the loop does not end right away as it should.  Instead when entering '0' it continues to ask for hrs(input) and pr(input) before running the first 'if' statement, then ending the program with "employees paid goodbye!"

Comment: @Angelica That's an incorrect explanation.

Comment: @Steven You need check the `loop break condition` after taking the input of 'name'.

Comment: think you so much, the code works.  I had no idea a break condition existed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the while loop condition is not evaluated except at the very start, before the loop body is executed. When `name` is set to '0', the condition `name != 0` becomes false but the rest of the while loop body will still get executed one more time.

The code below corrects the problem by testing this condition as soon as the user inputs the employee name and breaking out of the loop body early if the user entered '0':

```
print('We pay your employees payroll!')
while True:
    name = input("\nEnter employee or Enter '0' to quit: ")

    if name == '0':
        break

    pr = float(input("Enter Payrate: "))
    hrs = float(input("Enter Hours Worked: "))
    if hrs <= 40:
        print("Hours Worked: ", hrs)
        print("Payrate: ", pr)
        print("Basepay:", hrs * pr)
    elif hrs > 40:
        print('Hours Worked: ', hrs)
        print("Payrate: ", pr)
        print("Overtime Rate: ", pr * 1.5)
        print("Overtime Hours: ", hrs - 40)
        print("Basepay: ", (hrs - 40) * pr)
        print("Overtime Pay: ", (pr * 1.5) * (hrs - 40))
        print("Grosspay: ", (pr * 1.5) * (hrs - 40) + (pr * hrs))
print("Employees Paid, Goodbye!")
```

**Output**

```
We pay your employees payroll!

Enter employee or Enter '0' to quit: 1
Enter Payrate: 2
Enter Hours Worked: 2
Hours Worked:  2.0
Payrate:  2.0
Basepay: 4.0

Enter employee or Enter '0' to quit: 0
Employees Paid, Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not understanding the question clearly. I know the correct answer is being posted but I have rectified my mistake.

```
print('We pay your employees payroll!')    
while True:
    n = raw_input("\nEnter employee or Enter '0' to quit: ")
    if n.strip() == '0':
        break

    pr=float(input("Enter Payrate: "))
    hrs=float(input("Enter Hours Worked: "))

    if hrs <= 40:
        print("Hours Worked: ", hrs)
        print("Payrate: ", pr)
        print("Basepay:", hrs*pr)
    elif hrs > 40:
        print('Hours Worked: ', hrs)
        print("Payrate: ", pr)
        print("Overtime Rate: ", pr*1.5)
        print("Overtime Hours: ", hrs-40)
        print("Basepay: ", (hrs-40)*pr)
        print("Overtime Pay: ", (pr*1.5)*(hrs-40))
        print("Grosspay: ", (pr*1.5)*(hrs-40)+(pr*hrs))

print("Employees Paid, Goodbye!")
```

**Output**

```
We pay your employees payroll!
Enter employee or Enter '0' to quit: 1 
Enter Payrate: 10.5 
Enter Hours Worked: 2 
('Hours Worked: ', 2.0) 
('Payrate: ', 10.5) 
('Basepay:',21.0)                                                      
Enter employee or Enter '0' to quit: 0 
Employees Paid, Goodbye!
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue but causes the loop to immediately terminate.

Comment: Your code is still problematic. Have you actually tried running it? `We pay your employees payroll!0

Process finished with exit code 0` It should ask "Enter employee or Enter '0' to quit: "